# SSMS - Could someone help me write a query to calculate a monthly average from the product symbols listed below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

***Update. Caius Jard provided what I needed.***

This query works to create a 30 row moving average but I need it to calculate the average monthly settle prices for `PRODUCT_SYMBOL IN ('BK','CL','CY','WJ')` instead of the last 30 rows and I can't figure it out.

```
 SELECT PRODUCT_SYMBOL
        ,CONTRACT_YEAR
        ,CONTRACT_DETAIL
        ,TRADEDATE
        ,SETTLE
        ,AVG(SETTLE) OVER (
            PARTITION BY CONTRACT_DETAIL
            ORDER BY TRADEDATE 
            ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW
        ) AS MA30


    FROM Pricing.dbo.MasterReport$
    ORDER BY Tradedate ASC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and what YOU mean by "I need it to calculate the average monthly settle prices".

Comment: It's probably `AVG(SETTLE) OVER (
            PARTITION BY CONTRACT_DETAIL,  YEAR(TRADEDATE), MONTH(TRADEDATE)
        ) AS MA30` with a where clause to restrict the symbols but that's a guess because your Q is a bit light on detail

Comment: Thank Caius Jard. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
SELECT PRODUCT_SYMBOL
    ,CONTRACT_YEAR
    ,CONTRACT_DETAIL
    ,TRADEDATE
    ,SETTLE
    ,AVG(SETTLE) OVER (
        PARTITION BY CONTRACT_DETAIL
        ORDER BY TRADEDATE ASC
        ROWS 29 PRECEDING
    ) AS MA30
FROM Pricing.dbo.MasterReport$
ORDER BY Tradedate ASC
```